# Is it possible to set a single member of a complex-variable inside the variable table

Tags: drush

I want to use Drush vset to modify a subset of values stored in the 'variable' table's theme_themeName_settings record.

I've found references to vget and vset but all I've found so far is for the entire complex-variable.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drush does not support modifying elements inside a complex variable directly.  You could instead use php-eval to do this:

```
$ drush php-eval '$v = variable_get("theme_themeName_settings"); $v["key"] = "value"; variable_set("theme_themeName_settings", $v);'
```

Comment: Hey Greg.  Thank you very much for your post.  It does do what I asked for.  
What I trying for is to create php code I can put into a php script that reads the vget result into a array(?), test values, set other values depending on the results of the test.  

I can get your suggestion to run in a script but can’t access the $v variable in any other php command.  I suspect that the php-eval statement is “atomic.”  Is there a way do get access to it?

Thanks again.

--- Mike

Comment: If you need to do that, and you still want to use Drush, it is time to learn how to write your own drush commands.

Comment: Yes, your best bet is writing a Drush command. See https://www.drupal.org/project/drushify.  Halfway in between php-eval and a full Drush command is the Drush php-script command, which will run a sequence of php commands from a file.  A full Drush command will allow you to pass arguments and options, in addition to that.